# Canvas/fabricjs: How to group items?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web, fabricjs

I have an error when grouping elements. The error is only visible on the circles. Circles are rectangles. How to group items?

```
var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();
activegroup.clone(function (newgroup) {
    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    objectsInGroup.forEach(function (object) {
        canvas.remove(object);
    });
    canvas.add(newgroup);
});
```

[The full code](http://jsfiddle.net/millerish/fb7y8sfs/3/)

[Video bug](https://youtu.be/xhIDwpdx0jU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem when you create a circle object you put type is a 'rect', replace with 'circle'.

```
} else if (position.drawingType == "circle") {
                var circle = new fabric.Circle({
                    id: position.i++,
                    type: "circle",
                    radius: Math.abs(position.firstClickPositionX < position.lastClickPositionX ? position.firstClickPositionX - position.lastClickPositionX : position.lastClickPositionX - position.firstClickPositionX) / 2,
                    fill: 'red',
                    left: position.firstClickPositionX < position.lastClickPositionX ? position.firstClickPositionX : position.lastClickPositionX,
                    top: position.firstClickPositionY < position.lastClickPositionY ? position.firstClickPositionY : position.lastClickPositionY,
                    scaleY: 1,
                    scaleX: 1
                });
                canvas.add(circle);
```

Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb7y8sfs/4/)